# pass result of which to next command

Tags: bash, macos

I would like to edit a file with nano in bash on Mac which can be located via `which` command. Right now this is two steps:

**Step 1**

```
which start_dp.sh
```

> /usr/local/bin/start_dp.sh

**Step 2**

Copy and past the result of the first command

```
nano /usr/local/bin/start_dp.sh
```

**Is it possible to make this just one command?**

I tried the following two options which do not work.

```
nano | which start_dp.sh
which start_dp.sh | nano
```

Essentially, I would like to use the result of `which` as a variable for `nano`-Editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bash command substitution:

```
nano "$(which start_dp.sh)"
```

or equivalently, in an older form,

```
nano `which start_dp.sh`
```

In both cases, bash will substitute the output of the command into the command line, just like it would substitute a variable. The first form is preferable as it can easily be nested and does not need you to escape certain characters.

Alternately, if you want to use a pipe, you could use xargs, which will append the standard input to the provided command line and run it:

```
which start_dp.sh | xargs nano
```

Depending on what command you run, it might not work as well as command substitution, because the standard input will have been messed with.

If portability is desired, `command -v` should be preferred over `which`.

Comment: Since `which` is non portable, and non standard, use `command -v` instead. Other issue is your first command is missing double quotes to prevent word splitting and glob wildcards expansion. Here is a better alternative: `nano "$(command -p start_dp.sh)"`

Comment: @LéaGris You're right, I did miss the quotes. Portability is likely not an issue, given the [tag:macos] tag, but I did edit it in.